# "When interviewed about..."

Tags: passive-voice

> Dr Anne McClaren says that the primary motive
>   was an ethical one. When  __________ about the Frozen Ark, she jokingly said:
>   ‘I think Noah would have been proud of this project.’

I've already known that in the blank should be "inteviewed", but don't know why. My first guess was for "was interviewed" and one word for the passive form seemed weird.

Comment: Is that "9.6" meant to be in there? What does it mean?

Comment: ***Was*** *interviewed* only makes sense if it's preceded by a noun or pronoun. Assuming that *9.6* is a mistake, and not the name of a robot or something, then *was* should not be there. (*When* ***she*** *was interviewed* is correct, as is *when interviewed*, but *when was interviewed* is not.)

Comment: If 9.6 is the name of an outlet, like a magazine or blog or something, the blank could be "interviewed her".

Comment: 9.6. was a mistake, sorry, just edited it

Comment: 9.6 is the question number.  It's a multiple-choice question, and the available answers are: A) was interviewed, B) interviewed,  C) interviewing, D) was interviewing.  The key marks B) as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common transformation:

"When A was [verbed], (pronoun) " -> "When [verbed], A [other verb]".

It's idiomatic. There are other similar ones:

"After A was [verbed], (pronoun) [other verb]" -> "After being [verbed], A "

In a consistent grammar, those would work the same way, but they don't.